# configurar mojo maven para desplegar app

Tags: java, maven

Hola estoy tratando de ejecutar una app hecha en spring.
Mi arbol es el siguiente

```
./icova-webapp.
./services.
./etcetc.
```

ingreso a webapps y ejecuto `mvn spring-boot:run`

Aclaro que eso son los pasos que me dejaron para poder desplegar la app , aclaro también que desconosco maven  y me pidieron como un favor el levantar la aplicacion.

Haciendo lo anterior me sale el siguiente error

```
[DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.0.RELEASE:run' with basic configurator -->
[DEBUG]   (f) addResources = false
[DEBUG]   (f) agent = []
[DEBUG]   (f) arguments = []
[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = /root/evolplus/backendEvol/evolplus/icova/icova-webapp/target/classes
[DEBUG]   (f) mainClass = SocialApplication
[DEBUG]   (f) profiles = []
[DEBUG]   (f) project = MavenProject: com.applying:icova-webapp:1.0-SNAPSHOT @ /root/evolplus/backendEvol/evolplus/icova/icova-webapp/pom.xml
[DEBUG]   (f) skip = false
[DEBUG]   (f) useTestClasspath = false
[DEBUG] -- end configuration --
[WARNING]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: SocialApplication
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Mi archiv pom.xml dentro de icova-webapp directorio es

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
      <groupId>com.applying</groupId>
      <artifactId>icova</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.applying</groupId>
    <artifactId>icova-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>portal</name>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.applying</groupId>
          <artifactId>icova-common</artifactId>       
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.applying</groupId>
          <artifactId>icova-model</artifactId>        
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.applying</groupId>
          <artifactId>icova-service</artifactId>          
          <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>true</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Ahora bien la clase a la que referencia esta en

```
./icova-webapp/src/main/java/com/applying/icova/config/SocialApplication
```

La cual tiene en su codigo estas lineas

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
}
```

Leí que era necesario para poder desplegar la aplicacion , sin embargo creo que me falta algun paso el cual no me lo han especificado , cualquier ayuda seria de utilidad para mi.

Comment: Es que, le estás mintiendo al compilador :) A ver, dices que la clase está en: `./icova-webapp/src/main/java/com/applying/icova/config/SocialApplication` pero el compilador la está buscando en `[DEBUG]   (f) classesDirectory = /root/evolplus/backendEvol/evolplus/icova/icova-webapp/target/classes
` O cambias la ubicación de la Clase o le indicas al compilador que el directorio de clases es otro, ¿no?

Comment: Si eso me di cuenta, quiero saber como indicarle la ruta de la clase al compilador pues en el pom.xml no veo que se haga referencia , supongo que usa algun default , no es mi especialidad java , ni maven , asi que donde deberia cambiarlo ya que  supuestamente ese es el codigo que subieron a produccion otro equipo .

Answer (score 0):

En la etiqueta `<build>...</build>` de tu archivo `pom.xml` añade la etiqueta `<archive>...</archive>`que te indico más abajo (he dejado unos espacios sólo para que veas dónde está la modificación). Asumo que tu clase `main` se llama `SocialApplication`. Si no es esa, pones el nombre de la clase que hace de punto de entrada en la aplicación.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>

                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>main.SocialApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>

                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Si quieres empaquetar un `.jar` ejecutable, te sugiero que veas esto: [Maven: Set Up The Classpath](https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Add)